# Serial upvoting reversed after triggering reputation recalc

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, serial-voting, reputation-recalc

What happened:

1. A little before 19:09 yesterday I found the [reputation page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation).
2. I clicked `Trigger Reputation Recalc` to see what happened.
3. Within the next minute, I gained 92 reputation points. (See screenshot below)
4. This morning, I see `-105` reputation for `Serial upvoting reversed`

[image]

My question:

1. Was the increase a coincidence, or was it triggered by the recalc?
2. If it was triggered by the recalc, should it have been removed?

Thanks

Comment: Coincidence, rep recalc doesn't generate votes.

Comment: @Mat What exactly is rep recalc meant to do?

Comment: Nothing much anymore AFAIK. Used to be necessary to fix up rep from deleted posts or other corner-case scenarios (don't remember exactly what). I don't think there are actual use-cases left.

Comment: I just triggered a recalc and gained a net of 18 points.. Lost -2 to a downvote, and 20+ to 2 upvotes.. interesting.

Comment: It will occasionally fix some small discrepancies in your reputation, but for the majority of users it is useless as the system is designed to recalculate everything automatically now. Anyways, this is just a coincidence. The two would not be at all related to each other.

Comment: @animuson Im not sure the serial up voting question says anything about whether the rep recalc does or does not have anything to do with it. Your comment answer seems far more useful an answer than anything on that question

Comment: @Richard The two are not related to each other, so I imagine it wouldn't. The FAQ does, however, explain the possibilities of what causes those reversal statements. So through logical deduction, one can asume that the recalc did not cause it.

Comment: @animuson Since you're a diamond mod on SO, can you check if the upvotes were all the same user?

Comment: @Mooseman If they're all grouped together in one event, then they were all from a single user. If multiple users had serially upvoted you, you would have multiple reversal statements in your history (one per user).

Comment: @anmuson I suppose, but (ignoring the presence of your comment) I can imagine a future person having the same question, finding this and then being redirected to what is basically the SO documentation that requires interpretation rather than containing the answer. It just feels very un-stack-exchange-y

Comment: There's always a strong correlation between users using sock puppets accounts and them being interested in what effect that has.  You are always found out, one way or another.  Asking "what happened?" questions about it doesn't work either, as you found out ;)